# Realm listener with node

Tags: node.js, realm, listener

since the dotnet version of Realm.Server has a problem with certificates (see https://forums.realm.io/t/net-realm-server-notifier-startasync-never-connects-to-realm-cloud-instance-because-of-ssl-exception/1625), it was suggested by realm to use the nodejs package.

I am quite new to nodejs and so I tried to implement a change event listener using node. All that based on https://docs.realm.io/platform/using-synced-realms/server-side-usage/data-change-events#creating-event-handlers-in-node-js.

Unfortunatly I am not able to get it working. 
The node process stops running when realm is trying to connect (or at least is doing something in background). Anyhow the addListener method makes it stop.

I am sorry but there is not much I could provide. I've attached my sample code and the console output of the node process.

Does anyone has any experience with it? Or any tips where I could look up for some detailed logs, etc.?

Thanks in advance!!

```
'use strict';

const realm = require('realm');
const http = require('http');

const name = 'node-hello-world';
const port = '8888';

const app = new http.Server();

// the URL to the Realm Object Server
const realmUrl = '//myinstance.de1a.cloud.realm.io';
const userName = 'admin';
const userPassword = 'AnyPassword';

// The regular expression you provide restricts the observed Realm files to only the subset you
// are actually interested in. This is done in a separate step to avoid the cost
// of computing the fine-grained change set if it's not necessary.
const notifierPath = '^/([^/]+)/user-data';

//declare admin user 
let adminUser = undefined;

// The handleChange callback is called for every observed Realm file whenever it
// has changes. It is called with a change event which contains the path, the Realm,
// a version of the Realm from before the change, and indexes indication all objects
// which were added, deleted, or modified in this change
var handleChange = async function(changeEvent) {
    // Extract the user ID from the virtual path, assuming that we're using
    // a filter which only subscribes us to updates of user-scoped Realms.
    var matches = changeEvent.path.match("^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$");
    var userId = matches[1];

    var r = changeEvent.realm;

    console.log(`Change event for ${userId}`);
};

// register the event handler callback
async function main() {
    try {
        realm.Sync.setLogLevel('all');

        console.log("Creating instance of credentials");
        var credentials = realm.Sync.Credentials.usernamePassword(userName, userPassword);
        console.log("Logging in user.");
        adminUser = await realm.Sync.User.login(`https:${realmUrl}`, credentials);

        console.log(`Adding realm listener for path ${notifierPath}`);
        //if this line was called, the console will exit in a few seconds; if not the node process will continue running
        realm.Sync.addListener(`realms:${realmUrl}`, adminUser, notifierPath, 'change', handleChange);
        console.log("Added listener");
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log("An error has occured.");
        console.log(exception);
    }
}

main();

app.on('request', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('Hello World');
    res.end('\n');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`${name} is listening on port ${port}`);
});

------------------------------

Path>node app.js
Creating instance of credentials
Logging in user.
node-hello-world is listening on port 8888
Adding realm listener for path ^/([^/]+)/user-data
Global notifier: start()
Realm sync client ([realm-core-5.10.1], [realm-sync-3.10.0], protocol version 25)
Config param: max_open_files = 256
Config param: one_connection_per_session = 1
Config param: connect_timeout = 600000 ms
Config param: connection_linger_time = 30000 ms
Config param: ping_keepalive_period = 600000 ms
Config param: pong_keepalive_timeout = 600000 ms
Config param: fast_reconnect_limit = 60000 ms
Config param: enable_upload_log_compaction = 1
Config param: tcp_no_delay = 0
Added listener
Connection[1]: WebSocket::Websocket()
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Binding 'Path\realm-object-server\listener\realms.realm' to '/__admin'
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Activating
Opening Realm file: Path\realm-object-server\listener\realms.realm
Connection[1]: Session[1]: last_version_available  = 0
Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_server_version = 0
Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_client_version = 0
Using already open Realm file: Path\realm-object-server\listener\realms.realm
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Progress handler called, downloaded = 0, downloadable = 0, uploaded = 0, uploadable = 0, progress version = 0, snapshot version = 1
Connection[1]: Resolving 'myinstance.de1a.cloud.realm.io:443'
Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint '18.185.186.xx:443' (1/3)
Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '18.185.186.xx:443' (from '127.0.0.1:53094')
Connection[1]: Verifying server SSL certificate using root certificates, host name = myinstance.de1a.cloud.realm.io, server port = 443, certificate =
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Connection[1]: Verifying server SSL certificate using 155 root certificates
Connection[1]: Server SSL certificate verified using root certificate(29):
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Connection[1]: WebSocket::initiate_client_handshake()
Connection[1]: HTTP request =
GET /realm-sync/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Realm-Access-Token version=1 token="xxx"
Connection: Upgrade
Host: myinstance.de1a.cloud.realm.io
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 0TpYePZIZMhOid08TiAQzw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: io.realm.sync.25
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket


Connection[1]: WebSocket::handle_http_response_received()
Connection[1]: HTTP response = HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: upgrade
Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2018 11:22:13 GMT
sec-websocket-accept: A/hVVKTFOsJneK3U/SBQMisIyIg=
sec-websocket-protocol: io.realm.sync.25
Server: nginx/1.13.5
upgrade: websocket


Connection[1]: Will emit a ping in 467729 milliseconds
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: BIND(path='/__admin', signed_user_token_size=601, need_client_file_ident=1)
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: IDENT(client_file_ident=13, client_file_ident_salt=7274062357029523918)
Using already open Realm file: Path\realm-object-server\listener\realms.realm
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: IDENT(client_file_ident=13, client_file_ident_salt=7274062357029523918, scan_server_version=0, scan_client_version=0, latest_server_version=0, latest_server_version_salt=0)
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: MARK(request_ident=2)
Download message compression: is_body_compressed = 1, compressed_body_size=2054, uncompressed_body_size=5474
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=1, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025057956, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=370, changeset_size=370)
Changeset: 3F 00 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 01 0A 50 65 72 6D 69 73 73 69 6F 6E 3F 02 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 03 04 70 61 74 68 3F 04 04 55 73 65 72 3F 05 06 75 73 65 72 49 64 3F 06 0F 55 73 65 72 4D 65 74 61 64 61 74 61 52 6F 77 3F 07 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 08 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 09 04 75 73 65 72 3F 0A 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 0B 07 6D 61 79 52 65 61 64 3F 0C 08 6D 61 79 57 72 69 74 65 3F 0D 09 6D 61 79 4D 61 6E 61 67 65 3F 0E 09 75 70 64 61 74 65 64 41 74 3F 0F 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 10 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 11 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 12 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 3F 13 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 14 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 3F 15 08 6D 65 74 61 64 61 74 61 3F 16 03 6B 65 79 3F 17 05 76 61 6C 75 65 02 00 00 02 01 00 02 02 01 03 02 00 02 04 01 05 02 00 02 06 00 00 00 0B 07 02 00 00 0B 08 02 00 00 00 01 0B 09 0C 00 04 0B 0A 0C 00 02 0B 0B 01 00 00 0B 0C 01 00 00 0B 0D 01 00 00 0B 0E 08 00 00 00 02 0B 0F 02 00 00 0B 10 02 00 00 0B 11 0C 00 04 0B 12 08 00 00 00 04 0B 13 01 00 00 0B 14 0D 00 00 0B 15 0D 00 06 00 06 0B 16 02 00 00 0B 17 02 00 00
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=2, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025057963, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=208, changeset_size=208)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 04 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 D5 88 82 E0 F4 F3 85 E4 E0 00 A4 E3 DF D7 AD A0 B3 BA 07 02 08 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 02 01 D5 88 82 E0 F4 F3 85 E4 E0 00 A4 E3 DF D7 AD A0 B3 BA 07 00 09 72 65 66 65 72 65 6E 63 65 06 02 02 D5 88 82 E0 F4 F3 85 E4 E0 00 A4 E3 DF D7 AD A0 B3 BA 07 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 40 03 D5 88 82 E0 F4 F3 85 E4 E0 00 A4 E3 DF D7 AD A0 B3 BA 07 00 06 08 04 D5 88 82 E0 F4 F3 85 E4 E0 00 A4 E3 DF D7 AD A0 B3 BA 07 00 A1 F7 F2 DD 05 C0 ED 98 CB 03
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=3, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058022, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=202, changeset_size=202)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 04 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 C1 CF E7 BE C5 FA 94 88 07 AD E1 ED 8E 8E 83 8F D2 D0 00 02 08 2F 5F 5F 61 64 6D 69 6E 06 02 01 C1 CF E7 BE C5 FA 94 88 07 AD E1 ED 8E 8E 83 8F D2 D0 00 00 04 66 75 6C 6C 06 02 02 C1 CF E7 BE C5 FA 94 88 07 AD E1 ED 8E 8E 83 8F D2 D0 00 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 40 03 C1 CF E7 BE C5 FA 94 88 07 AD E1 ED 8E 8E 83 8F D2 D0 00 00 06 08 04 C1 CF E7 BE C5 FA 94 88 07 AD E1 ED 8E 8E 83 8F D2 D0 00 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 80 E3 BE 0A
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=4, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058024, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=201, changeset_size=201)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 04 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 02 07 2F 5F 5F 70 65 72 6D 06 02 01 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 00 04 66 75 6C 6C 06 02 02 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 40 03 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 00 06 08 04 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 80 EC B8 0B
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=5, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058029, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=221, changeset_size=221)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 04 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 02 16 2F 5F 5F 77 69 6C 64 63 61 72 64 70 65 72 6D 69 73 73 69 6F 6E 73 06 02 01 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 00 04 66 75 6C 6C 06 02 02 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 40 03 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 00 06 08 04 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 C0 82 EA 0D
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=6, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058030, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=215, changeset_size=215)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 04 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 BD F9 DE AC C3 D1 DF 9F D0 01 F7 EC A4 D8 9A 88 A5 A3 EB 01 02 10 2F 5F 5F 63 6F 6E 66 69 67 75 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 06 02 01 BD F9 DE AC C3 D1 DF 9F D0 01 F7 EC A4 D8 9A 88 A5 A3 EB 01 00 04 66 75 6C 6C 06 02 02 BD F9 DE AC C3 D1 DF 9F D0 01 F7 EC A4 D8 9A 88 A5 A3 EB 01 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 40 03 BD F9 DE AC C3 D1 DF 9F D0 01 F7 EC A4 D8 9A 88 A5 A3 EB 01 00 06 08 04 BD F9 DE AC C3 D1 DF 9F D0 01 F7 EC A4 D8 9A 88 A5 A3 EB 01 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 80 87 A7 0E
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=7, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058068, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=180, changeset_size=180)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 8E C8 AA AB FC ED C0 8E EB 01 C1 AC DB FD BE E9 C9 A9 0C 02 07 5F 5F 61 64 6D 69 6E 06 01 01 8E C8 AA AB FC ED C0 8E EB 01 C1 AC DB FD BE E9 C9 A9 0C 00 01 00 02 04 02 00 00 06 02 03 02 00 00 05 72 65 61 6C 6D 06 02 04 02 00 00 07 5F 5F 61 64 6D 69 6E 00 00 01 05 8E C8 AA AB FC ED C0 8E EB 01 C1 AC DB FD BE E9 C9 A9 0C 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 00
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=8, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058091, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=164, changeset_size=164)
Changeset: 3F 00 0A 50 65 72 6D 69 73 73 69 6F 6E 3F 01 04 75 73 65 72 3F 02 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 03 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 04 07 6D 61 79 52 65 61 64 3F 05 08 6D 61 79 57 72 69 74 65 3F 06 09 6D 61 79 4D 61 6E 61 67 65 3F 07 09 75 70 64 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 02 00 00 06 40 01 02 00 00 06 0C 03 02 00 00 02 B2 F8 DA D1 D7 8D 8F FF C7 01 BD EE F4 A5 FA DB D4 C2 FC 01 06 01 04 02 00 00 01 06 01 05 02 00 00 00 06 01 06 02 00 00 00 06 08 07 02 00 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 C0 99 B2 2B
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=9, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058092, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=163, changeset_size=163)
Changeset: 3F 00 0A 50 65 72 6D 69 73 73 69 6F 6E 3F 01 04 75 73 65 72 3F 02 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 03 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 04 07 6D 61 79 52 65 61 64 3F 05 08 6D 61 79 57 72 69 74 65 3F 06 09 6D 61 79 4D 61 6E 61 67 65 3F 07 09 75 70 64 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 02 01 00 06 40 01 02 01 00 06 0C 03 02 01 00 02 D5 C0 D0 E0 A8 C1 8C EB EE 01 9A F3 F6 F5 D9 BE D2 99 37 06 01 04 02 01 00 01 06 01 05 02 01 00 00 06 01 06 02 01 00 00 06 08 07 02 01 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 80 9E EF 2B
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=10, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058119, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=237, changeset_size=237)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 82 AD AB 8D A8 BD E3 D4 D9 01 FC DA CA A1 C6 CA F6 F0 EF 00 02 0B 2F 5F 5F 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 06 02 01 82 AD AB 8D A8 BD E3 D4 D9 01 FC DA CA A1 C6 CA F6 F0 EF 00 00 04 66 75 6C 6C 06 02 02 82 AD AB 8D A8 BD E3 D4 D9 01 FC DA CA A1 C6 CA F6 F0 EF 00 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 82 AD AB 8D A8 BD E3 D4 D9 01 FC DA CA A1 C6 CA F6 F0 EF 00 00 03 8E C8 AA AB FC ED C0 8E EB 01 C1 AC DB FD BE E9 C9 A9 0C 06 08 05 82 AD AB 8D A8 BD E3 D4 D9 01 FC DA CA A1 C6 CA F6 F0 EF 00 00 A2 F7 F2 DD 05 C0 97 DF 38
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=11, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025058319, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=203, changeset_size=203)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 F5 B4 A5 81 FC F6 F9 EC C5 00 A8 A5 E5 DA ED F8 FD F7 E5 00 02 0B 72 65 61 6C 6D 2D 61 64 6D 69 6E 06 01 01 F5 B4 A5 81 FC F6 F9 EC C5 00 A8 A5 E5 DA ED F8 FD F7 E5 00 00 01 00 02 04 02 01 00 06 02 03 02 01 00 11 6A 77 74 2F 63 65 6E 74 72 61 6C 2D 6F 77 6E 65 72 06 02 04 02 01 00 0B 72 65 61 6C 6D 2D 61 64 6D 69 6E 00 00 01 05 F5 B4 A5 81 FC F6 F9 EC C5 00 A8 A5 E5 DA ED F8 FD F7 E5 00 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 01
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=12, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025076163, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=243, changeset_size=243)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 E7 AB C7 A5 E1 B6 BF C4 E9 01 D3 B0 F1 FF C9 F1 B1 BD D0 01 02 1F 73 79 73 74 65 6D 2D 61 63 63 65 73 73 69 62 69 6C 69 74 79 2D 74 65 73 74 73 2D 75 73 65 72 06 01 01 E7 AB C7 A5 E1 B6 BF C4 E9 01 D3 B0 F1 FF C9 F1 B1 BD D0 01 00 00 00 02 04 02 02 00 06 02 03 02 02 00 11 6A 77 74 2F 63 65 6E 74 72 61 6C 2D 61 64 6D 69 6E 06 02 04 02 02 00 1F 73 79 73 74 65 6D 2D 61 63 63 65 73 73 69 62 69 6C 69 74 79 2D 74 65 73 74 73 2D 75 73 65 72 00 00 01 05 E7 AB C7 A5 E1 B6 BF C4 E9 01 D3 B0 F1 FF C9 F1 B1 BD D0 01 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 02
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=13, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119025559655, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=203, changeset_size=180)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 02 20 35 38 37 65 37 33 38 30 38 36 30 34 39 37 66 37 35 32 37 38 65 30 32 39 64 35 37 33 39 37 63 39 00 02 04 02 03 00 06 02 03 02 03 00 08 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 06 02 04 02 03 00 05 61 64 6D 69 6E 00 00 01 05 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 03
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=14, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119118101955, origin_file_ident=5, original_changeset_size=42, changeset_size=42)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 00 00 06 01 01 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 00 01
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=15, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119118127936, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=322, changeset_size=322)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 99 F1 D7 F8 83 8F 9D 9C C3 01 96 F3 C4 AC C6 B4 B3 89 B0 01 02 DC 00 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 2F 5F 5F 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 2F 35 38 37 65 37 33 38 30 38 36 30 34 39 37 66 37 35 32 37 38 65 30 32 39 64 35 37 33 39 37 63 39 2F 64 39 32 66 32 64 30 34 65 61 36 37 64 62 65 30 33 66 65 30 32 39 36 63 63 33 33 38 65 62 38 63 61 35 37 32 66 31 61 37 06 02 01 99 F1 D7 F8 83 8F 9D 9C C3 01 96 F3 C4 AC C6 B4 B3 89 B0 01 00 07 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 06 02 02 99 F1 D7 F8 83 8F 9D 9C C3 01 96 F3 C4 AC C6 B4 B3 89 B0 01 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 99 F1 D7 F8 83 8F 9D 9C C3 01 96 F3 C4 AC C6 B4 B3 89 B0 01 00 03 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 06 08 05 99 F1 D7 F8 83 8F 9D 9C C3 01 96 F3 C4 AC C6 B4 B3 89 B0 01 00 AF CE F8 DD 05 80 F4 A8 BE 03
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=16, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119120628443, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=317, changeset_size=317)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 A6 C0 A4 C6 AA A3 E3 EC 2F 99 B7 CE BF D8 9E A6 CA C0 01 02 DC 00 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 2F 5F 5F 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 2F 35 38 37 65 37 33 38 30 38 36 30 34 39 37 66 37 35 32 37 38 65 30 32 39 64 35 37 33 39 37 63 39 2F 37 65 35 36 38 34 36 33 36 66 39 63 62 31 32 31 35 32 35 63 64 62 66 38 31 32 33 39 31 32 64 36 31 30 66 39 62 38 62 30 06 02 01 A6 C0 A4 C6 AA A3 E3 EC 2F 99 B7 CE BF D8 9E A6 CA C0 01 00 07 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 06 02 02 A6 C0 A4 C6 AA A3 E3 EC 2F 99 B7 CE BF D8 9E A6 CA C0 01 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 A6 C0 A4 C6 AA A3 E3 EC 2F 99 B7 CE BF D8 9E A6 CA C0 01 00 03 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 06 08 05 A6 C0 A4 C6 AA A3 E3 EC 2F 99 B7 CE BF D8 9E A6 CA C0 01 00 F4 E1 F8 DD 05 C0 C9 9E D3 01
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=17, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119125943861, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=237, changeset_size=237)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 FB FF AB CD 89 DD 94 96 9C 01 D3 C3 DC DE BF E6 ED A0 D6 01 02 20 62 36 39 30 65 32 37 31 30 62 37 39 37 34 64 63 37 34 35 32 36 32 62 34 66 61 62 30 30 35 36 37 06 01 01 FB FF AB CD 89 DD 94 96 9C 01 D3 C3 DC DE BF E6 ED A0 D6 01 00 00 00 02 04 02 04 00 06 02 03 02 04 00 09 61 6E 6F 6E 79 6D 6F 75 73 06 02 04 02 04 00 20 30 37 31 62 32 66 35 38 33 66 35 35 31 36 34 35 34 30 32 35 64 61 37 33 62 33 66 63 62 30 63 62 00 00 01 05 FB FF AB CD 89 DD 94 96 9C 01 D3 C3 DC DE BF E6 ED A0 D6 01 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 04
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=18, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119125944405, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=319, changeset_size=319)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 C0 84 EF F4 9A DF 9A 8F 3A F9 BB AC E9 8C B7 CB B9 E0 00 02 DC 00 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 2F 5F 5F 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 2F 62 36 39 30 65 32 37 31 30 62 37 39 37 34 64 63 37 34 35 32 36 32 62 34 66 61 62 30 30 35 36 37 2F 63 61 39 38 33 37 30 61 37 64 32 37 65 36 65 66 31 35 64 30 32 33 62 61 61 39 61 38 64 39 61 66 65 37 30 65 39 61 32 35 06 02 01 C0 84 EF F4 9A DF 9A 8F 3A F9 BB AC E9 8C B7 CB B9 E0 00 00 07 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 06 02 02 C0 84 EF F4 9A DF 9A 8F 3A F9 BB AC E9 8C B7 CB B9 E0 00 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 C0 84 EF F4 9A DF 9A 8F 3A F9 BB AC E9 8C B7 CB B9 E0 00 00 03 FB FF AB CD 89 DD 94 96 9C 01 D3 C3 DC DE BF E6 ED A0 D6 01 06 08 05 C0 84 EF F4 9A DF 9A 8F 3A F9 BB AC E9 8C B7 CB B9 E0 00 00 B8 8B F9 DD 05 C0 9E 8F C1 01
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=19, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119221571875, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=237, changeset_size=237)
Changeset: 3F 00 04 55 73 65 72 3F 01 07 69 73 41 64 6D 69 6E 3F 02 07 41 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 3F 03 08 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 3F 04 0A 70 72 6F 76 69 64 65 72 49 64 3F 05 08 61 63 63 6F 75 6E 74 73 00 00 04 FF E6 E6 8D A6 9F DC 85 B8 01 CC D9 B6 E9 B8 99 A4 98 DF 01 02 20 66 39 36 62 35 34 36 37 66 35 38 64 63 61 37 36 66 36 64 65 64 66 30 62 36 34 65 31 34 37 32 38 06 01 01 FF E6 E6 8D A6 9F DC 85 B8 01 CC D9 B6 E9 B8 99 A4 98 DF 01 00 00 00 02 04 02 05 00 06 02 03 02 05 00 09 61 6E 6F 6E 79 6D 6F 75 73 06 02 04 02 05 00 20 62 31 64 34 61 30 32 32 65 37 34 33 33 65 31 37 61 36 37 30 39 32 63 33 66 66 30 36 34 65 36 64 00 00 01 05 FF E6 E6 8D A6 9F DC 85 B8 01 CC D9 B6 E9 B8 99 A4 98 DF 01 02 0E 0C 00 00 02 02 05
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=20, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119221573405, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=319, changeset_size=319)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 C0 E3 A0 CD C2 D2 E7 AD FD 01 A8 EB B2 F0 AC A7 FB 97 34 02 DC 00 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 2F 5F 5F 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 2F 66 39 36 62 35 34 36 37 66 35 38 64 63 61 37 36 66 36 64 65 64 66 30 62 36 34 65 31 34 37 32 38 2F 33 33 61 31 62 62 30 64 62 63 33 61 34 64 65 39 65 65 63 63 66 34 62 63 34 38 61 62 63 39 32 62 32 61 37 38 61 61 37 30 06 02 01 C0 E3 A0 CD C2 D2 E7 AD FD 01 A8 EB B2 F0 AC A7 FB 97 34 00 07 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 06 02 02 C0 E3 A0 CD C2 D2 E7 AD FD 01 A8 EB B2 F0 AC A7 FB 97 34 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 C0 E3 A0 CD C2 D2 E7 AD FD 01 A8 EB B2 F0 AC A7 FB 97 34 00 03 FF E6 E6 8D A6 9F DC 85 B8 01 CC D9 B6 E9 B8 99 A4 98 DF 01 06 08 05 C0 E3 A0 CD C2 D2 E7 AD FD 01 A8 EB B2 F0 AC A7 FB 97 34 00 C5 F6 FE DD 05 C0 9E 8F C1 01
Received: DOWNLOAD CHANGESET(server_version=21, client_version=0, origin_timestamp=119442393401, origin_file_ident=2, original_changeset_size=317, changeset_size=317)
Changeset: 3F 00 09 52 65 61 6C 6D 46 69 6C 65 3F 01 09 72 65 61 6C 6D 54 79 70 65 3F 02 09 73 79 6E 63 4C 61 62 65 6C 3F 03 04 55 73 65 72 3F 04 05 6F 77 6E 65 72 3F 05 09 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 41 74 00 00 04 D6 CB E6 D1 80 E9 B3 F3 CD 01 99 82 B2 C2 A8 95 C7 F2 15 02 DC 00 2F 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 2F 5F 5F 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 2F 35 38 37 65 37 33 38 30 38 36 30 34 39 37 66 37 35 32 37 38 65 30 32 39 64 35 37 33 39 37 63 39 2F 31 61 38 64 30 31 32 30 30 65 36 64 31 38 35 63 31 64 66 62 31 38 37 64 66 64 31 61 31 39 62 36 65 64 62 36 33 35 34 62 06 02 01 D6 CB E6 D1 80 E9 B3 F3 CD 01 99 82 B2 C2 A8 95 C7 F2 15 00 07 70 61 72 74 69 61 6C 06 02 02 D6 CB E6 D1 80 E9 B3 F3 CD 01 99 82 B2 C2 A8 95 C7 F2 15 00 07 64 65 66 61 75 6C 74 06 0C 04 D6 CB E6 D1 80 E9 B3 F3 CD 01 99 82 B2 C2 A8 95 C7 F2 15 00 03 CA F1 CD DC 8C BF 9C DD 05 8F FD 81 EC E5 E0 A8 8C 3F 06 08 05 D6 CB E6 D1 80 E9 B3 F3 CD 01 99 82 B2 C2 A8 95 C7 F2 15 00 D9 B3 8C DE 05 C0 8C 9B BF 01
Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: DOWNLOAD(download_server_version=21, download_client_version=0, latest_server_version=21, latest_server_version_salt=7217337837575967989, upload_client_version=0, upload_server_version=0, downloadable_bytes=4920, num_changesets=21, ...)
Using already open Realm file: Path\realm-object-server\listener\realms.realm
```

Comment: Seems like lower versions like 2.15.3 works.

Comment: Check notifier path is constraining path? const notifierPath = '^/([^/]+)/user-data';